# Retrieve specific data by splitting json data into chunks with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

how can I get the "symbol" data in a json data like below? I am using Python.

Also, how can I replace the "}" object in this data with replace?

```
[
{"symbol": "ZILUSDT", "positionAmt": "0", "entryPrice": "0.00000", "markPrice": "0.01728152", "unRealizedProfit": "0.00000000", "liquidationPrice": "0", "leverage": "20", "maxNotionalValue": "25000", "marginType": "cross", "isolatedMargin": "0.00000000", "isAutoAddMargin": "false", "positionSide": "SHORT"}, 
{"symbol": "FLMUSDT", "positionAmt": "0", "entryPrice": "0.0000", "markPrice": "0.00000000", "unRealizedProfit": "0.00000000", "liquidationPrice": "0", "leverage": "20", "maxNotionalValue": "25000", "marginType": "cross", "isolatedMargin": "0.00000000", "isAutoAddMargin": "false", "positionSide": "BOTH"}, 
{"symbol": "FLMUSDT", "positionAmt": "0", "entryPrice": "0.0000", "markPrice": "0.00000000", "unRealizedProfit": "0.00000000", "liquidationPrice": "0", "leverage": "20", "maxNotionalValue": "25000", "marginType": "cross", "isolatedMargin": "0.00000000", "isAutoAddMargin": "false", "positionSide": "LONG"}, 
{"symbol": "FLMUSDT", "positionAmt": "0", "entryPrice": "0.0000", "markPrice": "0.00000000", "unRealizedProfit": "0.00000000", "liquidationPrice": "0", "leverage": "20", "maxNotionalValue": "25000", "marginType": "cross", "isolatedMargin": "0.00000000", "isAutoAddMargin": "false", "positionSide": "SHORT"}
]
```

Comment: `symbols = [x['symbol'] for x in data]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the list of dictionaries after loading it as JSON (assuming it is `d`):

```
print(*[x['symbol'] for x in d],sep="\n")
```

Readable way:

```
for x in d:
  print(x['symbol'])
```

Load from a file:

```
import json
with open('json.txt') as f:
  d = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the sample. How can I tabulate this with "https://pypi.org/project/Columnar/"?

Answer (score 0):

To read json data use the `json.load()` function.

```
# Python program to read 
# json file 


import json 

# Opening JSON file 
f = open('data.json',) 

# returns JSON object as 
# a dictionary 
data = json.load(f) 

# Iterating through the json 
# list 
for i in data['symbol']: 
    print(i) 

# Closing file 
f.close()
```

> Source https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-json-file-using-python/

Comment: I don't see an `emp_details` key in the sample data.

Comment: That's because it's referred to the source code I added to the bottom...thanks for pointing it out; I just edited it to print "symbol" as the question asks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the sample. How can I tabulate this with "https://pypi.org/project/Columnar/"?

Comment: You should open a new question to ask that, anyway writing something like:
data = []
table = columnar(data, headers=['Race', 'Date', 'Location', 'Distance'], patterns=patterns)
print(table)
And replacing print(i) with data.append(i)

Answer (score 0):

That is a list of dictionaries.

```
import json

with open('myfile.json') as file:
    items = json.load(file)

for item in items:
    print(item['symbol'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the sample. How can I tabulate this with "https://pypi.org/project/Columnar/"?

Comment: @Fatihmzm Perhaps you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: I opened a new topic, can you help me?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612074/tabulating-data-received-with-json-with-python