# Tabulating data received with json with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I can parse the following data. but I cannot show it as a table in columnar. How can I chart this?

```
 for item in items:
     print(item['symbol'])
```

```
[
{"symbol": "ZILUSDT", "positionAmt": "0", "entryPrice": "0.00000", "markPrice": "0.01728152", "unRealizedProfit": "0.00000000", "liquidationPrice": "0", "leverage": "20", "maxNotionalValue": "25000", "marginType": "cross", "isolatedMargin": "0.00000000", "isAutoAddMargin": "false", "positionSide": "SHORT"}, 
{"symbol": "FLMUSDT", "positionAmt": "0", "entryPrice": "0.0000", "markPrice": "0.00000000", "unRealizedProfit": "0.00000000", "liquidationPrice": "0", "leverage": "20", "maxNotionalValue": "25000", "marginType": "cross", "isolatedMargin": "0.00000000", "isAutoAddMargin": "false", "positionSide": "BOTH"}, 
{"symbol": "FLMUSDT", "positionAmt": "0", "entryPrice": "0.0000", "markPrice": "0.00000000", "unRealizedProfit": "0.00000000", "liquidationPrice": "0", "leverage": "20", "maxNotionalValue": "25000", "marginType": "cross", "isolatedMargin": "0.00000000", "isAutoAddMargin": "false", "positionSide": "LONG"}, 
{"symbol": "FLMUSDT", "positionAmt": "0", "entryPrice": "0.0000", "markPrice": "0.00000000", "unRealizedProfit": "0.00000000", "liquidationPrice": "0", "leverage": "20", "maxNotionalValue": "25000", "marginType": "cross", "isolatedMargin": "0.00000000", "isAutoAddMargin": "false", "positionSide": "SHORT"}
]



How can I show it in a table like the one below?

     headers = ["Symbol", "EntryPrice", "side", "position"]
     symbols = [x['symbol'] for x in data]
     table = columnar(symbols, headers=headers)
     print(table)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "chart"?  Do you mean you want to create an actual image (i.e. JPEG or GIF)?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/Columnar/
no man i want to create like here

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of dictionaries. The easiest way is to wrap them into pandas' DataFrame, which handles that type out-of-the box.

```
import pandas as pd

tabulated = pd.DataFrame(items)
print(tabulated)
```

Comment: for sym in items:
    tabulated = pd.DataFrame(sym['symbol'], sym['entryPrice'])
    print(tabulated)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is an excellent solution, but you can natively present data in table format too:

```
for row in zip(*([key] + (value) for key, value in sorted(items.items()))):
    print(*row)
```